# Объясните что такое CursorLoader

Tags: android, adapter, cursor, мобильные-приложения, cursoradaper

Что такое CursorLoader , который вытаскивает данные из базы в Android? 
Как он работает и каков цикл его жизни?

Comment: Погуглить за вас? https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=android+cursorloader&oq=android+cursorloader&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4351j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Он делает асинхронные запросы на выборку данных из курсора. Жизненого цикла, как такого не имеет - "живет" по правилам обычного объекта Java.